# Javascript getUTCDate() and getUTCHour() with "01" not "1"

Tags: javascript

i already found a good solution to the named problem on this website. But it is not working in my script.

I hope someone could help. (Note: the function hour() day() month() changes with an onclick (that is still working correctly)

```
<script>    
 var d = new Date();
function hour(i) {
 d.setUTCHours(i);
 var h = addZero(d.getUTCHours());
}
function day(i) {
 d.setUTCDate(i);
 var d = addZero(d.getUTCDate());
}
function month(i) {
 d.setUTCMonth(i);
 var m = addZero(d.getUTCMonth());
}

function addZero(i) {
 if (i < 10) {
     i = "0" + i;
}
return i;
}

function img() {
 var dateString = d.getUTCFullYear() +""+ m +""+ d + "_" + h ;
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dateString; 
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables are local to the scope of the function they're defined in. You need to move the `var` statements outside.

```
<script>    
 var d = new Date();
 var h, m, day;
function hour(i) {
 d.setUTCHours(i);
 h = addZero(d.getUTCHours());
}
function day(i) {
 d.setUTCDate(i);
 day = addZero(d.getUTCDate()); // changed the name here to avoid conflicting
}
function month(i) {
 d.setUTCMonth(i);
 m = addZero(d.getUTCMonth());
}

function addZero(i) {
 if (i < 10) {
     i = "0" + i;
}
return i;
}

function img() {
 var dateString = d.getUTCFullYear() +""+ m +""+ day + "_" + h ;
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dateString; 
}

</script>
```

Comment: But you're never calling these functions? And no, global variables is certainly not a good pattern, just `return` the values.